# reCaptcha overlooks form validation on iOS device

Tags: html, ios, forms, validation, recaptcha

I've been having some trouble recently with reCaptcha specifically on iOS mobile devices. I've been testing validation by trying to get past a form **without filling in details** but making sure the reCaptcha is checked.

- **What I expect to happen:** I expect the form validation to kick in when I click send while the reCaptcha is checked.
- **What actually happens:** The form isn’t validated and is treated as
  filled in due to the reCaptcha being checked, so next page opens.

Main reason I find this odd is because when testing this exact scenario on my laptop the validation kicks in as well as on android devices, iOS device shows no sign of it :( Is this a compatibility issue with browsers and OS? Below are snippets of code:

## Form HTML + PHP

```
<div class="formalign" align="center">
 <?php
  if ($response != null && $response->success) {
  echo "Hi " . $_POST["name"] . " (" . $_POST["email"] . "), thanks for submitting the form!";
 } else {
 ?>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" required data-required-message="Name is required">
            </label>
            <label>
                <input name="email" type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required data-required-message="Email is required." data-type-message="You must provide a valid email address.">
            </label>
            <label>
                <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="50" placeholder="Enter your message here" style="font: 13.3333px Arial;"></textarea>
            </label>
            <div align="center" class="g-recaptcha" data-theme="dark" data-sitekey="MY_SITE_KEY" style="margin-top: 1em;"></div>

            <input type="submit" value="Send" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset">
        </form>
        <!--js-->
        <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=en-GB'></script>
 <?php } ?>
</div>
```

## reCaptcha PHP

```
<?php

// grab recaptcha library
require_once "recaptchalib.php";

// your secret key
$secret = "MY_SECRET_KEY";

// empty response
$response = null;

// check secret key
$reCaptcha = new ReCaptcha($secret);

// if submitted check response
if ($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]) {
    $response = $reCaptcha->verifyResponse(
        $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
        $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]
    );
}

?>
```

I initially used Google Chrome's device mode, this worked as expected but **the test needs to be done on a physical iOS device to see the issue at hand**.

Please let me know if any further details are required and thanks in advance.